# smslib and configuration with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, smslib

while looking the java code for sending SMS from GSM Modem I found many links associated with smslib. I got one .jar file(smslib-3.3.2.jar) and a .zip file(smslib-v3.5.3.zip) associated with it. Can I use the jar directly with my projects.. Then what is the need for configuring the smslib.. As a java beginner I am confusing with these external tools and their use.

Comment: have you got the answer or any idea for implementing smslib with eclipse.. Please share.

Comment: I got some installation guidelines and files from [here](http://smslib.org/doc/installation/). But I could not send message using that setup and java code (available on net).

Comment: recently i completed my project and able to send the sms using smslib java. Let me know if i can help you.